# Searchkick, how to use aggregations on a join table

Tags: searchkick

I'm a searchkick newbie. 
I read the docs and I understand how to use aggregations, and I also watch some video.

Every tutorial I read uses aggregation on attributes on the main indexed model. 
By the way I understand that I can use also aggregation on associations.
But my situation is different.

I have a complex situation

```
class Product < ProductDatabase::Base
 searchkick
 has_many :products_features
end

class ProductFeature < ProductDatabase::Base
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :feature
end

class Feature < ProductDatabase::Base
 has_many :products
end
```

ProductsFeatures is the join table between the features and the products, and in the join table I have the values I need in my aggregations...

```
t.string "raw_value"
t.string "presentional_value"
t.integer "product_id"
t.integer "feature_id"
t.boolean "searchable", default: false
```

Example:

For every category of products, for example, "smartphone", I need to add an aggregate search for the display size.

The smartphone display sizes for every product in my database is inside the ProductsFeatures table, with a specific feature_id (the one that corresponds to the display size).

I already create a search system with activerecord query and it works, but every time I need to manually add the part of the code I need to filter results. 
I'm starting to learn ElasticSearch and SearchKick and I want to use a project that I already have...